# Найти в текущей папке и подпапках файлы и папки в имени которых есть "+" и "&" и заменить их на " plus " и " and ", удалив двойные пробелы

Tags: windows, bat

Имена файлов/папок могут быть на латинице и кириллице, содержать искомые символы в любых количествах и комбинациях

К сожалению не смог найти учебника по синтаксису и не понимаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замена символов в переменной производится с помощью конструкции `%varName:str1=str2%` или `!varName:str1=str2!` (заменит все вхождения `str1` на `str2`).
Подробнее об этом можно узнать с помощью команды `help set`.

Команда `dir /s /b` рекурсивно выводит все имена файлов и папок.
Цикл `for` проходится по каждой строке из вывода команды и запускает блок `do`.
В нем происходит проверка имени и переименование файла/папки.

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b') do (
    set "fileName=%%i"
    set "eFileName=!fileName:+=plus!"
    set "eFileName=!eFileName:&=and!"
    if not "!fileName!"=="!eFileName!" move "!fileName!" "!eFileName!"
)
```

Comment: Это работает! Спасибо за помощь! Спасибо за подробный разбор. Может у вас есть ссылка на учебник по языку?

Comment: @ГригорийК учебника не нашел, сам учился используя команду `help` и https://ab57.ru/cmdlist.html